# Getting 0 when trying to calculate slope

Tags: java, math, int, zero

Here is the specific equation that's giving me 0 when it should be giving me -0.4 (-2/5)

```
slope2 = ((yVals[i+2] - originY) / (xVals[i+2] - originX));
```

(-2 - 0) / (2 + 3)

slope2 is a double

yVals[] is an int array

origin is an int

Why does it keep returning 0? I know the variables are being called correctly because I've done a println on the different vals and they are correct.

Comment: So all of the variables on the right side of the equation are ints?

Comment: you are performing integer division.

Comment: Split every subexpression into its own variable and see how the values progress once you start combining them.

Comment: So, maybe i need to temporarily convert the int's to double's?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel yes i've done that and confirmed they are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing integer division in Java, where math done using `int`s must yield an `int`, so the division truncates anything beyond the decimal point.  This means that in Java, `-2 / 5` is `0`.  It's not enough that the target of the assignment is a `double`.  One of the operands must be `double` (or `float`) to force floating-point arithmetic.

Cast one of the operands to the `/` operator to a `double` to force floating-point arithmetic.

```
slope2 = ( (double) (yVals[i+2] - originY) / (xVals[i+2] - originX));
```